# how to clean detail mass on regex

Tags: regex

how to delete the detail with mass regex ?

example

before delete :

```
Live => [US] United States | example1@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 
Live => [US] United States | example2@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 
Live => [US] United States | example3@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 
Live => [US] United States | example4@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 
Live => [US] United States | example5@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015
```

after delete :

```
example1@yahoo.com
example2@yahoo.com
example3@yahoo.com
example4@yahoo.com
example5@yahoo.com
```

please with demo on regex101 :)
thanks before

Comment: what is code regular expression for delete this detail :) i need

Comment: No, what you _need_ is to learn how to ask a question. You're supposed to have read the How to Ask article before even considering it, so you know everything there is to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
.*?\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|.*
```

And replace with `$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uA8yD8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with an empty string.

```
^[^|]*\|\s*|\s*\|.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uA8yD8/3)

In php, you need to use `preg_replace` function.

```
$re = "/^[^|]*\\|\\s*|\\s*\\|.*/m";
$str = "Live => [US] United States | example1@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 \nLive => [US] United States | example2@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 \nLive => [US] United States | example3@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 \nLive => [US] United States | example4@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 \nLive => [US] United States | example5@yahoo.com | Checked on 5:59 pm - May 17, 2015 ";
$subst = "";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```